# Setting multiple form values in to a JavaScript Object dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to optimize my code a little and was wondering if anyone here can give me a helping hand.

Before I explain my issue let me offer you my html and js/jquery code for your viewing pleasure!

HTML :

```
<tr>
<td>
    <input email="a@a.com" value="4560" type="checkbox" id="task_checked">
</td>
<td>a@a.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <div>
        <span>E-Mail: </span><input id="4560" type="text" name="added_email" class="added_email">
        <span>Enter Book Name: </span><input id="4560" type="text" class="category"> 
    </div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
    <input email="b@b.com" value="6012" type="checkbox" id="task_checked">
</td>
<td>b@b.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <div>
        <span>E-Mail: </span><input id="6012" type="text" name="added_email" class="added_email">
        <span>Enter Book Name: </span><input id="6012" type="text" class="category"> 
    </div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
    <input email="c@c.com" value="5604" type="checkbox" id="task_checked">
</td>
<td>c@c.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <div>
        <span>E-Mail: </span><input id="5604" type="text" name="added_email" class="added_email">
        <span>Enter Book Name: </span><input id="5604" type="text" class="category"> 
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Hopefully that didn't scare you off!

Here is my Jquery.

```
var newTasksArr = {};
 $("#task_checked:checked").each(function() {
var email = $(this).attr("email");
var id = $(this).val();
newTasksArr[id] = email;
});


var AddedEmailsArr = [];

var inputs = $('input.added_email'), tmp;
$.each(inputs, function(i, obj) {
tmp = {
    'Task_ID': $(obj).attr('id'),
    'email': $(obj).val(),
    'category' : $(obj).siblings('.category').val(),
};

AddedEmailsArr.push(tmp);
});
```

As you can see currently I have two Jquery functions which I am trying to make in to one.

Let me show you guys/gals what the output looks like.

```
//output for var newTasksArr = {};
Object { 4560="a@a.com", 6012="b@b.com", 5604="c@c.com" }

//output for var AddedEmailsArr= {};
[ 
Object { Task_ID="4560",  email="f@f.com.com",  category="example1" }, 
Object { Task_ID="6012",  email="g@g.com.com", category="example2" }, 
Object { Task_ID="5604",  email="z@z.com", category="example2" }
]
```

In order to optimize my code I would like to get rid of the two objects and make in to one object.

Below is what I would like it to look like.

```
[ 
Object { Task_ID="4560",  email="f@f.com.com",  category="example1" }, 
Object { Task_ID="6012",  email="g@g.com.com", category="example2" }, 
Object { Task_ID="5604",  email="z@z.com", category="example2" }, 
Object { Task_ID="4560",  email="a@a.com" }, 
Object { Task_ID="6012",  email="b@b.com" },
Object { Task_ID="5604",  email="c@c.com" } 
]
```

Hopefully my question makes sense and I would truly appreciate any help from you guys with this question. Please feel to ask me for anything for clarifications.

Thank you.

Comment: You haven't really asked a question here, just told us what it should look like. Why should it look like this? Could you provide some context?

Comment: @Prisoner Hi, because currently I am passing two objects to my backend and I would like it to be one instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to completely get into all of the details. But I think you may need to take a step back and rethink the approach. ID's should be unique and you may look into use the "data" attributes instead of creating your own attributes. It seems like you are on the right thought process, but not solid foundation.